# How to get money from using admob

Tags: google-play, admob

I just made an account on `Admob` , I want to integrate my app with it , but what i didnt understand is how it pay to me ? I am finding where i need to enter my account information where i receive the money , but no good help is there for it , any experience use , please help me out , about your experience

Answer (score 5):

> AdMob begins processing payments for a month's earnings one month
>   after the calendar month in which they are earned. There is a
>   processing time of approximately two to three weeks. You will receive
>   an email notifying you when payment processing begins. This happens on
>   the date that funds are removed from your AdMob account and is the
>   date recorded in the Account Summary page of the Account tab.
>
> In order for the processing to begin, you must meet the threshold for
>   the method of payment you have selected.
>
> $20 if you selected PayPal $100 if you selected ACH/Wire You must meet
>   the threshold to be eligible for payment. If your total payable
>   earnings are less than the threshold amount, AdMob rolls your earnings
>   over to the following month.

Cf : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307281?hl=en

And for payment methods :

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2956524

Comment: What this `On August 31, 2014, legacy AdMob will no longer be available.` statement means ? and when i go to account section my Payment and billing all are empty

Comment: There's a new interface for interacting with Admob (now that google is bringing together its products under one roof) and you'll need to enter some new payment details too.

Comment: @FiddleMeRagged But its not showing me any option there where i enter my account or payment details

Comment: yes am using this , i want to embed its add in my app

Comment: can any one tell me why Bank tell me that there is NO such amount credited from Admob while in my account 104 USD has been wired Transferred and ad mob generate bill also even two time i have earned and both time ad mob release payment but Bank is telling there is NO such amount has been received please suggest why this happen